# Multiple VueSelect

Tags: vue.js, vue-select

I am obtaining from an API the data to fill a **v-select** type component, the component is filled correctly and I also obtain the options that the user already had assigned (**multiple**)

[image: The selected items are showed as selected]

And the v-select component are filled correctly

[image: Options are correctly loaded]

But when i try to add another option occurs the next

[image: The another options disappear]

Here is the Source Code

```
<validation-provider
        #default="validationContext"
        name="skill"
      >
        <b-form-group
          label="Skills"
          label-for="skill_id"
          :state="getValidationState(validationContext)"
        >
          <v-select
            v-model="itemData.skills"
            :dir="$store.state.appConfig.isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'"
            multiple
            :options="skillOptions"
            :clearable="false"
            :reduce="(val) => val.value"
            input-id="skill_id"
          />
          <b-form-invalid-feedback
            :state="getValidationState(validationContext)"
          >
            {{ validationContext.errors[0] }}
          </b-form-invalid-feedback>
        </b-form-group>
      </validation-provider>
```

Here i have the array of objects, with multiple elements

**itemEdit.value.skills**

Then **map** to get a reduced array with only the **value** and **label**

I have probed using only the **label** without **value** and the result is the same

```
const openEdit = item => {
  isSidebarActive.value = true
  itemEdit.value = item
  itemEdit.value.skills = item.skills.map(skill => ({
    value: skill.id,
    label: skill.skill,
  }))
  isAdd.value = false
}
```

Everything apparently goes right, the **v-model** match correctly with the available options, the problem comes when the user interact with the **vSelect** to add another item, the already selected items disappear

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks for listen, the problem was solved removing:

**:reduce="(val) => val.value"**

From

```
<v-select
            v-model="itemData.skills"
            :dir="$store.state.appConfig.isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr'"
            multiple
            :options="skillOptions"
            :clearable="false"
            :reduce="(val) => val.value"
            input-id="skill_id"
          />
```

Answer (score 3):

Based on [this page](https://vue-select.org/guide/values.html#transforming-selections) o the Vue Select Documentation, the `reduce` prop is usually meant for use with a `label` prop, and is only needed if you provide an object to v-select.

I suspect you are providing an array of primitives in your v-model (ie itemData.skills is an array of strings) instead of an array of objects.  If it is an array of objects instead, then I suspect you either don't have a [label] key on the object (the default that label is set to), or you don't have a [value] key (what you are trying to return with your reduce prop).

Ideally, you would give us an example of your data coming in for us to be able to help you better.

Comment: Hi @RadicalTurnip, i have supplemented the question, the skill array is an object array, thanks